# python: how to check if a specific pattern log file is there if a directory exists

Tags: python

I am running a command (ls -ltr /a/b/c/filename*.log) in a shell inside a python code. The issue is if directory /a/b/c dont exist it generates error, also if there is no log file with pattern filename*.log it fails. So i want to put check for both directory and file pattern before running the command in shell. So far, I tried below code.

```
def subprocess_cmd(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
    return proc_stdout

DIR_PATH = "/a/b/c"
if os.path.exists(DIR_PATH):
    files = os.listdir(DIR_PATH)
    if "filename" in BASENAME for BASENAME in files:
        CMD = "ls -ltr /a/b/c/filename*.log"
        LOGFILE = subprocess_cmd(CMD)
```

Getting below error

```
    if "filename" in BASENAME for BASENAME in files:
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please note that I am not checking whether a particular file exists or not. I am concerned about the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
try:
   ....
except Exception as e:
   #some code to handle the missing directories
```

Comment: can you do this without using exception handling and modify the line where I am getting error.

Comment: this isn't correct syntax: if "filename" in BASENAME for BASENAME in files: Basically you're introducing a "bridge", the BASENAME. You can simply write if "filename" in files. But I reckon this is also not correct, given "filename" is a string, so probably: for f in filemane: if f.find("filename"> 0):

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if [f for f in files if f.startswith(BASENAME)]:
    ...
```

This will create a list of files whose name begins with the `BASENAME` and check if this list is not empty.

Note that it does NOT check for the extension (but you may of course add `f.endswith(".log")` as a second condition).